# Disabling dates on a date picker . jquery ui control

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

Am trying to disable the datepicker for the dates, current date +3 and the dates going back. l would like it to exclude Saturday and sunday when adding the +3 thus looking only at the working days  monday to friday.

am currently using the function below but it does not leave out weekends.

```
$(function () {
     $( "#dkt input" ).datepicker({ minDate: +3 });
    });
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in to do that. You'll need to write your own code that calculates the third weekday after current date.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the weekends, use the beforeShowDay utility:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-noWeekends

To disable before the current date plus three days, use minDate:

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    minDate: 3
```

});